# Changing elements path in CakePHP 2.0

Tags: cakephp, mobile, path, element, cakephp-2.0

It's possible to change the View path on App Controller using:

```
$this->viewPath = $newPath;
```

Is it possible to change the Elements path?
I really need it for a mobile version and i load them from controllers with ajax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an if-else construct to check if it is mobile or not, and load the appropriate element accordingly:

```
if ($mobile) {
    $element = $this->element('mobile/helpbox');
} else {
    $element = $this->element('desktop/helpbox');
} 

echo $element;
```

Answer (score -2):

with the following statement u can change the used view:

`$this -> render(‘yourviewname’);`

If the used view is stored in another folder like 'mobile' use the following statement:

`$this -> viewPath = ‘mobile’;`

Comment: I know how to change the view path. My question was about how to change the Element Path.